# react js app on safari giving an error

Tags: reactjs, safari, create-react-app

I have created a small react app

I have created it using create-react-app utility.
It is working fine in chrome with out any errors.

Same app is not working in safari. Following is the error

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Map
```

Can't quite understand what this error is or how I can solve it.

Comment: which version of safari?

Comment: Not sure what is the latest version. From what I downloaded it's 5.1.7

Comment: `Map` is an ES6 feature that was introduced in Safari 8 (http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-Map). The latest Safari is 11, but is only available on Mac. Your version is the last one available for windows, and was released in 2012! If you need to test Safari, then it should be done on a Mac with up to date browser, or it just wont be representative

Comment: I got the answer for this question and added it as an answer myself

Answer (score 0):

As per react 16 release documentation, we have to use polyfills for Set and Map to support older browsers.
I have used polyfills for ES6 Map and Set and it worked out fine